# Can't use flutter_local_notifications

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification

I using the latest version of [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) in my project, but keep getting this issue

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Mi A2 in debug mode...
/home/xxx/Desktop/flutter_linux_1.22.6-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-4.0.1+1/android/src/main/java/com/dexterous/flutterlocalnotifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1260: error: cannot find symbol
            List<NotificationChannel> channels = notificationManagerCompat.getNotificationChannels();
                                                                          ^
  symbol:   method getNotificationChannels()
  location: variable notificationManagerCompat of type NotificationManagerCompat
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_local_notifications:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

My flutter version

```
Flutter 1.22.6 • channel stable
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0
firebase_core: ^1.0.0
flutter_local_notifications: ^4.0.1+1
```

Comment: Hi there,  Please, try this command in the terminal into the project: flutter clean

Comment: @islamakhrarov still same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I finally reproduced such kind of issue and could solve it by upgrading or downgrading the plugin or remove the plugin from .pub_chace and install it, in your case `flutter_local_notifications`.

Comment: which version of the plugin you using?

Comment: I'm using sound null safety version

Answer (score 2):

open android\build.gradle
find this

subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')

```
project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core' &&
                !details.requested.name.contains('androidx')) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.1"
        }
    }
}
```

delete project.configurations.all and all its content

the new code now looks like this

`subprojects { project.evaluationDependsOn(':app') }`

flutter clean
flutter pub get